# fluentd S3 use part of log tag in bucket path

Tags: amazon-s3, logging, fluentd

Is there a way to use first part of the tag in bucket path while uploading to aws s3 using fluentd?
I can use the entire tag like this:

```
<store>
 @type s3
 s3_bucket "#{ENV['S3_BUCKET']}"
 s3_region "#{ENV['S3_REGION']}"
 path "#{ '%Y/%m/%d/' + ENV['PATH_NAME'] + '/' }${tag}/"
 store_as json
 s3_object_key_format %{path}%{time_slice}_${tag}_%{index}.%{file_extension}
 time_slice_format %Y%m%d-%H%M
 ...
</store>
 <buffer tag,time>
...
</buffer>
```

Is there a way to use instead something like

```
path "#{ '%Y/%m/%d/' + ENV['PATH_NAME'] + '/' }${tag_part[0]}/"
```

I've tried fluentd record_transformer to parse the tag but I'm only able to add the parsed part into the record and not use it outside

```
<filter *.**>
  @type record_transformer
  <record>
    my_added_parsed_tag ${tag_parts[0]}
  </record>
</filter>
```

this adds correctly the first part of the tag to the log entry. But if I try to use this part of record in the path variable, e.g:

```
path "#{ '%Y/%m/%d/' + ENV['PATH_NAME'] + '/' + record['my_added_parsed_tag'] }"
...
 <buffer tag,time,my_added_parsed_tag>
...
</buffer>
```

fluentd container fails with the error

```
fluentd exited with code 1
fluentd  | (eval):3:in `eval_embedded_code': undefined local variable or method `record' for #<Binding:0x00007f5b986f5a68> (NameError)
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:193:in `instance_eval'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:193:in `eval_embedded_code'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:109:in `scan_double_quoted_string'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:82:in `scan_string'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:75:in `parse_literal'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/v1_parser.rb:131:in `parse_element'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/v1_parser.rb:96:in `parse_element'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/v1_parser.rb:96:in `parse_element'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/v1_parser.rb:44:in `parse!'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/v1_parser.rb:33:in `parse'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config.rb:71:in `parse'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config.rb:52:in `build'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:682:in `setup_global_logger'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/supervisor.rb:624:in `configure'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/command/fluentd.rb:351:in `<top (required)>'
fluentd  |  from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
fluentd  |  from <internal:/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/3.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb>:85:in `require'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/bin/fluentd:15:in `<top (required)>'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/bin/fluentd:25:in `load'
fluentd  |  from /usr/local/bundle/bin/fluentd:25:in `<main>'
fluentd exited with code 1
```

I'm using fluentd:edge-debian docker image

Comment: In embedded Ruby block, you can try splitting it yourself e.g. `#{ ... + tag.split('.')[0] }`.

Comment: @Azeem I've tried it like this `path "#{ '%Y/%m/%d/' + ENV['PATH_NAME'] + '/' + tag.split('.')[0] }" ` but it fails with error`(eval):3:in `eval_embedded_code': undefined local variable or method `tag' for #<Binding:0x00007fc117aa57c8> (NameError)`

Comment: So, apparently the `tag` directly is not available. Maybe, it needs to be `${tag}`. Please try `#{ ... + $tag.split('.')[0] }` or `#{ ... + ${tag}.split('.')[0] }`. I'll try to test this on my side and update here later if it's still an issue by then.

Comment: @Azeem both don't work for me, `path "#{ '%Y/%m/%d/' + ENV['PATH_NAME'] + '/' + ${tag}.split('.')[0]  }"` fails with `fluentd  | /usr/local/bundle/gems/fluentd-1.16.1/lib/fluent/config/literal_parser.rb:168:in 'scan_embedded_code':  '%Y/%m/%d/' + ENV['PATH_NAME'] + '/' + ${tag}.split('.')[0]  }" (Fluent::ConfigParseError)`, and `path "#{ '%Y/%m/%d/' + ENV['PATH_NAME'] + '/' + $tag.split('.')[0]  }"` fails with `fluentd  | (eval):3:in 'eval_embedded_code': undefined method 'split' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Then, it's not available here in the embedded Ruby code block. You already have tried using `record` but it didn't work either. Can you not use different sections for different paths?

Comment: @Azeem we would like to be able to sort similar logs from different sources into different buckets, e.g. company1.syslog1 and company1.syslog2 to go to the folder "company1"

Comment: You may rewrite tags of events using https://docs.fluentd.org/output/rewrite_tag_filter and they'll automatically be routed to their respective tagged section. Apart from that, you can create an issue on S3 plugin repo (https://github.com/fluent/fluent-plugin-s3) to handle your scenario. Maybe, they'll be able to provide this right away.